# How to start android activity without showing main activity in the back

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

I'm developing an application containing 2 activities:

1. Main activity launched where user starts the app.
2. Second activity is launched where user clicks on a button widget
   on the home screen.

I created my widget and the view that will be displayed when the user clicks on the widget button.

**My problem**: The second activity UI is displayed above the main activity, the main activity is visible because the second activity layout is transparent, because I want to let the home screen still be visible when clicking in the widget.

How can I launch only the second activity without launching the main activity below it? I tried to remove `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` in the main activity from the manifest file, widget works but when I install my app in the phone there's no app icon installed so I can't launch the main activity.

I hope that I have expressed my problem.

Comment: Have you tried calling finish() on the first activity after launching the new activity?

Comment: if u dont know the answar please dont down vote any questions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem like this :

1- I added to the main activity attributes in the manifest file :

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

I tested it does not makes loading time when re-launching activity longer than usually because this attribute does not erase the app cache and keeps the intent instance in the memory.

2- Add this to main activity class :

```
@Override
void onPause()
    {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
    }
```

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to finish the first `Activity` right after you start the second `Activity`

```
startActivity(<secondActivity>);
finish();
```

Comment: Thank you, but i can't do this because i lannch the second activity from the widget not from the main activity, so i can't access to the main acivity object to finish it.. any idea how i can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can either finish your main activity after you start your second activity:

```
startActivity(secondActivity.class);
finish();
```

Or in your application manifest you can use the noHistory flag on your main activity, so it calls finish itself when you navigate away from it.

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Comment: Tank you, i'm looking for this, i found also that i can do this by adding android:launchMode="singleTask" to my activity properties, which is the better solution ? if i use android:noHistory="true" then android will never stock the app memory cache data so it can make the app loading time much longer every time ?

Comment: noHistory will just make it so whenever the mainActivity is launched, when you exit it (Either by closing it or going to a new activity) it will be finished. Whether this has negative consequences for your cache I'm not sure, you'd have to look into it. singleTask will finish other activities in the stack, so it'd probably have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps having a different intent action and intent filter associated with the second activity will work. Have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html). The notepad application example is should be similar to what want need to do.

Comment: i have already different intent actions and filters for the 2 activities.

Comment: Then you can just invoke the second activity directly using its intent filter. You can do this by using the `Intent.setData()` method call to pass a uri your second activity can handle. Here's some [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html) that may help you.